# including pages from wordpress query

Tags: wordpress

i am running the following query:

```
<?php $parent = $post->ID; ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=3&orderby=parent&post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="home-container" class="post-<?php the_id();?>">
<div id="home-thumb">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbs');?>
</div>
<div id="home-title">
<h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
</div>
<div id="home-content">
<?php the_content();?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am trying to include certain posts posts with the id's of 2,15 and 23 and then exclude everything else. I thought this would be a simple process of something like the following but i was wrong:

```
<?php query_posts('include=2,15,23&showpost=3&orderby=parent&post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated,

thanks Dan

Comment: In your comment you said you are trying to include post ids but in your title you said excluding pages from wordpress. Please confirm the task first. Thanks